# How to allow Firebase database-realtime access (read/write) to only my domain https://

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How can I set up the realtime database authorisation to only accept request from my domain and not someone random in the world ?

EDIT: The answers marked as duplicate revolve around the domains in the EMAILS of users. Not the source of the HTTP request. Therefore they do not answer this question.

Comment: The provided questions do NOT answer this question. This is not a duplicate.